# Which topology is used in practice to couple a noise generator to a signal?

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise, adder

I want to add noise (from a noise generator hardware) to a sine wave signal. The sine wave signal is coming from a function generator. The noise is generated by another hardware.

What is the method used in practice for such purpose? I came across the following topology:

[image]

Is there any advantages to using a non-inverting or an inverting  adder in this case? I'm asking because I'm planning to superimpose (add) white noise (from a white noise generator) onto a sine wave (from the function generator). So I'm not going add two signals but signal plus noise.

Comment: You have, in fact, two signals that you need to add together.  It doesn't matter that one of the signals is white noise.  You have two sources that must be added together.

Comment: What range of frequencies of interest?

Comment: @Andyaka The sine-wave between 0.1Hz up to 1kHz. Both signal Noise I can set the amplitudes.

Comment: Just use a small audio transformer to add the signals passively (saving batteries saves the earth and may, in a small way reduce outbreaks of coronavirus)

Comment: @Andyaka At 0.1Hz transformer might not work its approaching to DC.

Comment: What about the noise spectrum?

Comment: @Andyaka Uniform noise.

Comment: Inverting adder (virtual earth summing point) isolates the input signal sources from each other. That's why all the audio mixers I know do it that way.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I see, very good information. Maybe you write this as an answer so I can accept it.